# Opening Window Its own Minheight and MinWidth

Tags: .net, wpf, window, sizetocontent

I want to open a window with its own MinHeight and MinWidth, without setting SizeToContent property and without specifying any Height and Width of window in WPF. Kindly let me know how can I achieve the same in WPF. Thanks

Comment: How did you try to do it? Show us some code!

Comment: <Window x:Class="LoginView"               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      MinWidth="295"  MinHeight="165" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

Comment: Currently I am displaying window at its MinWidth and MinHeight by setting SizeToContent property. But I want set SizeToContent property "Manual" then want to open window at its MinWidth and MinHeight. Kindly give me any suggention on this. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the restriction of not setting width or height?

Comment: Can I set height and width in wpf base resource as window minheight. So that I do not write same in window page for each window. Thanks

Comment: You can do that in a style.. create a style for window and put it in a common place like app.xaml so that you can user it anywhere you want

Comment: exactly, I want something like this by setting window height and width in resource as per window minheight and minwidth which defined in the every window(page specific). But how can I get window minheight and minwidth in resource file(app.xaml). Kindly suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your window should open based on the size specified in MinHeight and MaxHeight without specifying SizeToContent property then you need to set MaxHeight and MaxWidth also.
You need to set the same value to Maxheight and Maxwidth properties. Try below XAML snippet

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApplication.Test1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test1" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"
    MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="100"
    SizeToContent="Manual">
```